# how to rename file via batch from other folder?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-rename

I have this which works if the batch is in the folder, but fails when I run it from any other folder

```
@echo off
if exist "E:\[0] EE\feed\*.ss" (
  if not exist "E:\[0] EE\feed\O.ss" (
    FOR %%A IN ("E:\[0] EE\feed\*.ss") DO REN "*.ss" "O.ss" > nul 2>&1 
  )
)
@echo on
pause
```

also (if its possible) is there a way how to **not** rename file if file is "O2.ss" so basicly I need to renname any file with extension .ss (if such file is in the folder) to O.ss, but avoid renaming file O2.ss ??

Comment: Your code is renaming files with the extension of `.ass`.   Also, I am not understanding why you are not using the `FOR` variable `%%A` to rename the file.  Essentially that is your problem as to why it does not work when the batch file is in another folder.  The code is setup to rename files in the current working directory.  Why wouldn't you do this: `REN "%%~A" "O.ss"`

Comment: @Squashman apologies, I edited my Q/code. I need to specify the directory and run my batch from another drive.

Comment: I am not satisfied after reading your code and question together that I understand your intention. You appear to have a known directory, `"E:\[0] EE\feed"`, containing `1` file with an unknown name and an extension of `.ss` which you want to rename to `O.ss`. You wish to exclude a file named `O2.ss` from being renamed. Can you confirm that my understanding is absolutely correct? Also, why are you excluding a file named `O.ss` in your code? _especially because renaming a file to the same name doesn't appear destructive_.

Comment: @Compo yes, you are correct. my known folder can contain 0-3 files with .ss extension. and to answer that exclusion... point was to not continue further with next commend

Comment: @JudgeDredd, you stated there could be `0-3` files with an `.ss` extension in that directory. You're excluding any named `O`, any named `O2` and now any which begin with `E`. The more exclusions, the more awkward the script looks. Perhaps you would be better off providing a list of all possible exclusions so that we can formulate a more efficient or succinct script.

Comment: @Compo basicly this is my full exclussion list: `o1,o2,o3,e,e1,e2,e3,n,n1,n2,n3,nc,nc1,nc2,nc3,00,01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,p` all of them with .ss extension, so what I did was (thx to squashman formula) I nested IFs like this: `IF /I NOT "%%~A"=="00.ss",IF /I NOT "%%~A"=="01.ss", IF /I NOT "%%~A"=="22.ss"...` etc

Comment: @JudgeDredd, we could simplify your exclusion coding by using a file with all of the listed exclusions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would accomplish the task.  Pretty straight forward when you use the `IF` command to do the heavy lifting.

```
@echo off
cd /D "E:\[0] EE\feed\"
if exist "*.ss" (
    if not exist "O.ss" (
        FOR %%A IN (*.ss) DO (
            IF /I NOT "%%~A"=="O2.ss" REN "%%~A" "O.ss" > nul 2>&1
        )
    )
)

pause
```

Comment: in case if I would need to add `IF /I NOT "%%~A"=="B3.ss"` where I should nest it?

Comment: I added 2nd if not after 1st one like `IF /I NOT "%%~A"=="O*.ss", IF /I NOT "%%~A"=="E*.ss"` but when I have `zz.ss` and `e1.ss` it renames **e1** not **zz**. what do I miss?

Comment: @JudgeDredd, when doing a string comparison, you cannot use wildcards.